# Can a Majorana field $\psi$ be charged under some $U(1)$ with a charge other than zero?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model, majorana-fermions, charge-conjugation

I know Majorana particles have to be electrically neutral because electric charged is conserved.

My question, however, is whether at all a Majorana field $\psi$ be charged under any $U(1)$ (other than $U(1)$ of electromagnetism) with a nonzero $U(1)$ charge? If yes, how? Doesn't the defining condition $\psi=\psi^c$ always ***mathematically*** constrain all $U(1)$ charges to be zero? Let me explain why I think so. Suppose, we assign a nonzero U(1) charge $\alpha$ to the field $\psi$ so that $$\psi^\prime=e^{i\alpha}\psi.$$ What is the charge of the field $\psi^c$? It can be easily seen that $$\psi^{c\prime}=C\bar{\psi^\prime}^T=C\gamma^{0T}\psi^{\prime *}=e^{-i\alpha}C\bar{\psi}^T=e^{-i\alpha}\psi^c.$$

Therefore, for any $U(1)$ charge $\alpha$ assigned to the field $\psi$, the complex-conjugated field $\psi^c$ will have the charge $-\alpha$. What does it imply for a Majorana particle where $\psi=\psi^c$? **It necessarily implies that $\alpha=0$ i.e., Majorana fields cannot be charged under any U(1) group**. Therefore, it is **not** at all possible to assign a nonzero $U(1)$ charge for this fields. Am I missing something here?

***If my conclusion is correct, what does it mean to say that a Majorana mass violates $U(1)$ quantum number (such as lepton number) by 2 units?*** I must be missing some caveat. What is that?

Comment: @downvoter May I know the reason for the downvote?

Comment: yes, Majorana fermions violate lepton number conservation

Comment: @Kosm What does it mean to violate lepton number when you cannot assign nonzero lepton number to Majorana fields? My question is that.

Comment: right. But you can assign lepton numbers to other fermions, and Majorana mass term will break the global L symmetry

Comment: @Kosm What do you mean by other fermions? Do you mean assigning lepton number for a Dirac fermion and writing a Majorana mass for that same Dirac fermion? Is that allowed?

Comment: no, I mean the Dirac fermions: electron, muon,.. They do have nonzero L. Then the mass term of Majorana neutrino will lead to non conservation of L

Comment: @Kosm I don't quite understand your point. My question is, if a Majorana fermion $\psi$ cannot have nonzero U(1) quantum number, what does it mean to say that $m\psi\psi$ violates U(1) number by 2 units. Here, where does other fermions come from? I have a Majorana fermion $\psi$ and Majorana mass $m\psi\psi$.

Comment: Like flavor symmetries, *L* may well be an approximate symmetry of the charged lepton sector--the only sector directly observable: νs are monitored through their coupling to charged leptons. So far, no violations of *L* have been detected, but if they are, the source of these violations would be the *ultra-small* Majorana mass for νs, whose mixed partners *would* carry *L* but for the presence of this mass term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Majorana field can *not* be charged under the U(1) group. However, it can be charged under the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ subgroup of U(1). Under the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ transformation, $\psi\to\psi'=-\psi$, any Majorana fermion Hamiltonian (such as the Majorana mass $m\psi\psi$) should be *invariant* under this $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry, which is also called the **fermion parity** symmetry. Therefore we can assign a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ quantum number (i.e. the fermion parity) to the Majorana field, which is the lepton number modulo two. In other words, the lepton number is not conserved for the Majorana fermion, but it can only change by 2, so the parity of the lepton number is still conserved.

In the derivation, the charge conjugation condition $\psi'=\psi'^{c}$ requires:
$$e^{\mathrm{i}\alpha}\psi=e^{-\mathrm{i}\alpha}\psi^c=e^{-\mathrm{i}\alpha}\psi,$$
which implies
$$e^{\mathrm{i}\alpha}=e^{-\mathrm{i}\alpha}.$$
This equation has **two** solutions: $\alpha=0$ and $\alpha=\pi$. The solution of $\alpha=\pi$ corresponds to the non-trivial $\mathbb{Z}_2$ charge. In general, all composite fields made out of the Majorana field (such as $\psi_a\psi_b\psi_c\cdots$) can carry the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ charge. Let $q=0,1$ be the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ charge, then a charge-$q$ operator $O_q$ transforms under the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry as
$$O_q\to O'_q=e^{\mathrm{i}q\pi}O_q.$$
One can see the Majroana field $\psi$ itself has $q=1$, which has one unit of lepton number (modulo two). However it is meaningless to talk about the U(1) lepton number of the Majorana fermion, because the U(1) symmetry has been broken down to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. So more presicely, we should say the Majorana field is **fermion parity odd** (meaning that it carries one unit of the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ quantum number). The Majorana mass $m_{ab}\psi_a\psi_b$, the interaction $V_{abcd}\psi_a\psi_b\psi_c\psi_d$ and all other terms that appear in the Hamiltonian have $q=0$, which are **fermion parity even** (meaning that they do not carry the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ quantum number).

Comment: How does the Majorana mass $m\psi\psi$ violate your $\mathbb{Z}_2$ charge by 2 units rather than $2\pi$ units? That part is not clear. Moreover, in your notation what will be 1 unit of lepton number? @ Everett You

Comment: Majorana field can not have a U(1) quantum number $L$, it only has a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ quantum number $q = L \mod 2 = 1$. The mass term violates the U(1) quantum number  by $L=2$ units, but it preserves the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ quantum number $q=L \mod 2 = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let me write it down as an answer. Yes, Majorana neutrino cannot be charged under $U(1)$, including global $U(1)_L$ of Lepton number. What we mean by violation of $L$: the processes, like [neutrinoless double beta decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_beta_decay), sensitive to the Majorana mass term will violate $L$ by two units, which for the given example corresponds to the production of two electrons, and (surprise!) no neutrinos.